# Macro Not Opening workbook even though all workbooks are present

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to macros.
The following macro is not working even though it works in other workbooks and folders so i can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
Sub TryMacro()
'
' TryMacro
'
Dim orders As String
orders = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*ORDERS-Confirmed.xlsx")
Dim active_users As String
active_users = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\USERS_-_Active*.xlsx")
Dim active_users_business As String
active_users_business = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\USERS_-_Active_Business*.xlsx")
Dim businesses As String
businesses = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NEGOCIOS*.xlsx")

Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & orders
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & active_users
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & active_users_business
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & businesses

End Sub
```

This is a snippet of the entire macro as it doesn't go past this.

The error I get is:
[image]

[image]

Even though the workbooks i'm trying to open is in the same folder as the macro.

Comment: If you put this code in your Personal (since it's referencing XLSTART in the error), `ThisWorkbook` will refer to the Personal, you're likely meaning to use `ActiveWorkbook` or have the macro in the workbook you want to base it around.

Comment: It seems that orders is a Null string, which means there is no such file in ThisWorkbook.Path

Comment: @Blackcat: Yes and No. Code was probably moved to the Personal Workbook and therefore `ThisWorkbook.Path` points to the XLSTART folder (as Notus_Panda pointed out). `Dir` doesn't find any files there and `orders` (and the other variables) will be blank.

Comment: Try changing `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`. Note that the active workbook will need to be saved for it to have a path (i.e., not still called Book1.xlsx). Otherwise, you can hard code the path but I'm assuming you haven't because it's dynamic.